# save & load html response as object in a file - python

Tags: python, object, python-requests, python-object

My goal here is to save and load the response for later use. (It's could be after a few days).
I want to be efficient and not to crawl websites anytime, but to keep them as files and load them when needed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get(link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")

"""" Example of function that I would like to load the responce here instead."""

def getValue(page):
    return page.find('td', attrs={'class': 'Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)'}).text
```

type of html:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

type of page_content:

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make request and save response to file:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text

with open('workfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

And when you need to access previously saved data:

```
with open('workfile') as f:
   read_data = f.read()
```

Comment: You can also use `r.content` instead of `r.text`

Comment: Yes, we can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests with "r.content"
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

I just wanted to focus on writing/reading of request responses.